# Schedule python script, System user

Tags: python, batch-file

I scheduled a Windows task to run bat file-based python script every day. It works with my account but then it's dependent on my password. I want to run it using the system account (NT AUTHORITY SYSTEM), but the environment (anaconda) is installed in my user folder so it has no access. Can you advise the approach? Should I install a new environment outside of the user folder?

Comment: add `conda` to system variable and add python of conda to path

Answer (score 0):

You could package your Python script in a `.exe` file using [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/).
This would allow you to run your script on any PC because Python and the environment is packaged within the executable.

Btw.: use `pyinstaller SCRIPT.py --onefile` to get a single executable.